# how can I merge some inputs into one

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I want to know how I can merge some inputs into the database-parameter DATETIME:

I want the user to select the date in a [dropdown-list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected) and also one for the time.

*Something like this:*
[image]

But I dont know how to merge these inputs to the DATETIME-parameter that I set up in the model:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: {message: "..."}
  validates :titel, presence: {message: "..."}
  validates :location, presence: {message: "..."}
  #validates :time, presence: {message: "..."}
  #validates :date, presence: {message: "..."}
  validates :date_time, presence: {message: "..."}

end
```

I hope you understand my question.
Thanks for help.
If you need more information, let me know.

---

***EDIT:***
This is my controller-method. Did I understand you ?

```
def add_now
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    @schedule.date_time = DateTime.parse("#{params[:year]}-#{params[:month]}-#{params[:day]}")
    if @schedule.valid?
      @schedule.save
      #UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver #BestätigungsEmail versenden
      flash[:notice] = 'Ein neuer Termin wurde erstellt.'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      render :action => "add"
    end
  end
```

This is my view-erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Date_Time:</strong><br/>
  Tag: <%= schedule_form_builder.select :date_time, [['01','01'],['02','02'],['03','03']] %>
  Monat: <%= schedule_form_builder.select :date_time, [['01','01'],['02','02'],['03','03']] %>
  Jahr: <%= schedule_form_builder.select :date_time, [['2013','2013'],['2014','2014'],['2015','2015']] %>
  <%= schedule_form_builder.text_field :date_time, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Passwort erstellen' %>
  <%= show_field_error(@schedule, :date_time) %>
</p>
```

There is no day, month or year so I didn't understand you correctly.
Would be nice if you can help me again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a specific form helper for doing this. You should change your view to:

```
<%= schedule_form_builder.datetime_select(:date_time) %>
```

It will pass the params as:

```
{
  "date_time(1i)"=>"2015", # year
  "date_time(2i)"=>"7",    # month
  "date_time(3i)"=>"29",   # day
  "date_time(4i)"=>"11",   # hour
  "date_time(5i)"=>"52"    # minute
}
```

And `ActiveRecord` will automatically understand this format. There's no need to mess with this params manually. So you do build your instance as usual, e.g `Schedule.new(schedule_params)`.

Best!

Comment: I seperate it with `<%= schedule_form_builder.date_select(:date_time) %>` and `<%= schedule_form_builder.time_select(:date_time) %>`. Just btw to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine this three parameters to one string and use `DateTime::parse` method to convert string to DateTime:

```
schedule.date_time = DateTime.parse("#{params[:year]}-#{params[:month]}-#{params[:day]}")
```

Or just initialize the DateTime object from the numbers:

```
schedule.date_time = DateTime.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i)
```

Comment: In the controller, where you processing your form submit.

Comment: See EDIT at the question.

Comment: Yes, you've got the idea. Of course it depends how you pass the form `params`, I assumed it is `:year`, `:day` and `:month`

Comment: `schedule_form_builder.select :year ...`, `schedule_form_builder.select :month ...`, `schedule_form_builder.select :day ...`. Please read at least [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form).